# How does the block-device config setting on the LXD Juju charm work?

Tags: juju, openstack, ceph, nova, lxd

I am deploying Openstack using the Juju Openstack LXD bundle.
With this bundle block storage is provided by a Ceph cluster.

The LXD charm has a block-device config setting that defaults to /dev/sdb. Would you be able to explain how this setting, Nova and Ceph work together so that the LXD container gets its storage backed by Ceph? ... or not as the case may be.